# What is the meaning of this white arrow kind of thing in minimap?

Tags: battlefield-4

What is the meaning of this white arrow kind of thing in minimap?

**Map**: Zavod 311

**Game mode**: Obliteration

[image: Minimap]

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I believe it's the direction the 'Bomber' is flying from. What map is this on is it on the China Rising maps?

Comment: The map is Zavod 311, game mode Obliteration.

Comment: Hmm, then I'm not sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is showing that a friendly Man-Portable Active Protection System (MP-APS) is active and the white area is showing the "protected" area. If the white line is blinking it means it is offline/recharging.

For an overview of how the MPAPS works, see [this Battlefield 4 wiki page](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/MP-APS), however, it is a support gadget that works very similar to active protection. It will destory any tank shells/TOW missiles/LAV cannon that is fired at it, and although it has a limited use range, when use effectively it can reduce the amount of damage friendly armor can take hugely.

Comment: Perfect. I just watched this video on YouTube and it explains everything. You can add this video to your answer if you think it is helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cCiLkWCMhA